# Antlr plugin descriptor failed to load intellij

Tags: plugins, antlr4

I am trying to install the tools for antlr for intellij, but i get an Error "Fail to load plugin descriptor from file". I have tried both the Jar and the ZIP available on the official anltr page. Both have had the same error message. Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: Load it as a library instead of a plugin.